# Why does includegraphics complain with # in filename?

Tags: pdftex, includegraphics, compilation-error

I am very noob with latex.

I have to compile latex file with following code:

`\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{### LOGO ###}\\`

Compilation with pdflatex fails with

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempb.
<to be read again> 
                    
l.27 \includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{### LOGO ###}
                                                \\
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

Which file does it awaiting? I have `LOGO.SVG` in directory with the file.
Or is there other reason to fail I simply don't know?

**IMPORTANT**: unfortunality I can not change tex file for now, this is not my part of project.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Why are you writing `### LOGO ###` and not just `LOGO`? Note that DVG is normally not among the supports image formats for latex, but that can be fised via certain packages.

Comment: the file is really called that??? It's not simply a placeholder for a a project-specific file to be added?  If you really must use `\myhash` defined as `\edef\myhash{\string#}` then `\myhash\myhah\myhash\space LOGO...`

Comment: It's how file was stored in DB. We do refactoring on our ARM since it's developers abadon it last year. So I simply don't know why it was written this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the TeX file, you will not be able to resolve this issue for either:

1. `#` in a filename won‘t be accepted by TeX because it is a special character. David pointed out a solution if your filename is really `### LOGO ###` but I suspect that.
2. According to your question the file is called `Logo.svg`. As of now, svg cannot be directly read by TeX, the simplest solution would be to convert the svg to a pdf.

The easiest solution would be to convert your Logo.svg to Logo.pdf and then change your code to read: \includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Logo}